# Magento 2.3.2. No 'Cost' price attribute on 'Advanced Pricing' tab

Tags: magento2.3, advanced-pricing

I am using Magento 2.3.2, should I have a 'Cost' attribute under the 'Special Price From' attribute on the 'Advanced Pricing' tab? I have, from top to bottom -

- Special Price
- Special Price From
- *My tiered prices*
- Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
- Display Actual Price

Just wondering as it would be handy for us to use. I have looked under Magento 2.3 documentation and it does refer to a 'Cost' attribute but nothing shows up in a search of my product attributes. Is this something that was not included in 2.3.2? I could add a new attribute I guess, but if there's one already for the job then I'll use that.

If anyone can shed light on this I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have the '*cost*' attribute as it is part of the M2.3.2 default setup.

You can find the attribute as part of the product default attributes setup in `Magento/Catalog/Setup/CategorySetup.php` in the method `getDefaultEntities()` which is called by `installEntities()` method of the `Magento/Eav/Setup/EavSetup.php`.

Comment: It is there. There is an element called   'user_defined' => true which is also on two other attributes, both of which are also hidden.

Comment: can you check if maybe there is a customization somewheere or a 3rd party module that hides it?